# Why is my scheduleAtFixedRate delay ignored?

Tags: java, android, runnable, scheduledexecutorservice

I would like to execute a function every 4 seconds, and the first set of the code works perfectly fine that "testing" is printed every 4 seconds.

```
ScheduledExecutorService SES = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
            SES.scheduleAtFixedRate(new UpdateGraph(), 4, 4, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

public class UpdateGraph implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        Log.v("testing", "testing");
    }
}
```

However, if I have a for looping inside the runnable, "testing" is no longer delayed like I asked.

```
public class UpdateGraph implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
            final double t = i;
            final int y = i;
            lineGraphPosture.addNewPoints(PointPosture.singlePoint(t, getNextX().get(y)));
            graphView.repaint();
            Log.v("testing", "testing");
        }
    }
}
```

I understand the problem is with the for loop, but fail to figure out why?

Please could some one give some guidance =)

Comment: You're running a loop.  Of course all numberOfFiles will be printed out in quick succession.  They're happening without any delay between them.

Comment: What would you suggest is the correct way introduce daly between elements of numberOfFiles?

Comment: `Thread.sleep`?

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful of uncaught exceptions when using a `SchedulorExecutorService`. If your `UpdateGraph` throws an exception at runtime, no more execution will be scheduled.

I would advise you to wrap this block inside a try/catch and log an eventual exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you want your Runnable to be executed only *numberOfFiles* times, then a scheduled executor is the wrong choice here. Rather take a SingleThreadExecutor and do something like this:

```
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for (int i = 0; i < numberOfFiles; i++) {
    executor.submit(runnable);
    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(4L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```